# Nexus S 4.0.3 (OTA) missing icon in the phone app

Tags: applications, samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, calls, home-screen-shortcuts

How can I solve missing icon issue? Restarted couple of times doesn't help.
Note: It was fine for a couple of months back. When it start happening, I just need to reboot, but now it's permanent.
The action buttons in the phone app should look like this:

[image: ics actionbar]

But instead my phone app screen look like this:

[image: ics phone app]

Comment: Are you running an official OTA update, or a custom ROM?

Comment: what is that little "tick" in the right corner? maybe based on your DPI all the buttons do not fit and it needed to be put in a menu.

Comment: @Chahk yes, I'm running offical OTA, no unlock, root etc. For cm I do have other device ;)

Comment: @Ryan that's exactly my question. Pressing menu does nothing though.

Comment: @user802421 Have you tried a factory reset yet?

Comment: Not yet. I was hoping not to atm.

Comment: @Ryan pressing the "tick" (with a needle;) show contacts to add to the call.

Comment: I want to guess that maybe 4.0.3 maybe changed what you are used to seeing if you didn't change anything on the device. other then that... I have nothing, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that that isn't the way it should be? Today I recived a 4.0.4 system update for my Nexus s. Try updating yours from 4.0.3 to 4.0.4.

Edit:
That is the way its ment to be. Me and many people I know have it like that. Where did you get the first image of the dock bar from?

Comment: I'm on 4.0.4 and it's happened from time to time. I still cannot reproduce the error though.